# Search list of filenames with wildcards

Tags: c#, file

I have a list of filenames and one DOS-style wildcard as the search parameter.

```
List<string> filenames = FileNames;
```

How can I receive only files which match my wildcard ("p*.doc", "w*.*", "??r.doc?", and so on)?

Yes, I know about Directory.GetFiles, but I don't have a directory. Only filenames.

Comment: Use this pattern = new WildcardPattern(patternString);
pattern.IsMatch(stringToMatch);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is make a regex from the DOS-style wildcard filename specification, then you can select the filenames from the list which match the regex, something like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static string DosWildcardToRegex(string dwc)
        {
            string s = "";
            foreach (char c in dwc)
            {
                if (c == '.') { s += @"\."; }
                else if (c == '*') { s += ".*?"; }
                else if (c == '?') { s += "."; }
                else s += Regex.Escape(c.ToString());
            }
            return "^" + s + "$";
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string userWildcardSpec = "p*.xls*";
            string reWildcard = DosWildcardToRegex(userWildcardSpec);

            Regex re = new Regex(reWildcard, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

            var sampleFilenames = new List<string>() { "a1.xls", "p2.txt", "p1.xls", "p234.xls", "p7.xlsx" };

            var matchedFilenames = sampleFilenames.Where(f => re.IsMatch(f));

            Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\r\n", matchedFilenames));
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Which outputs:

```
p1.xls
p234.xls
p7.xlsx
```

- In a regex, a `.` is a special character which means "any character", so it needs to be escaped as `\.`.
- In a DOS wildcard, `*` means zero-or-more of any character, which is `.*?` in a regex (the `?` makes it "non-greedy").
- In a DOS wildcard, `?` means one character, which is `.` in a regex.
- In case there is some other special regex character, they are escaped where necessary.
- The `^` and `$` mean the start and end of the string respectively, so it won't get an unwanted match from the middle of a filename.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way:

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices;
...
var filenames = new List<string>() { "b.pdf", "al.rtf", "mel.doc"};
var matched = filenames.Where(f => LikeOperator.LikeString(f, "*.d*", CompareMethod.Text));
```

Comment: It is indeed compact and easy, but be aware that the [documention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.compilerservices.likeoperator.likestring) has the note "This helper method is not meant to be called directly from your code."